# Python Peewee not creating unique constraints in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, peewee

I'm creating my schema by using this snippet of code:

```
from peewee import *

db = PostgresqlDatabase('db', user='user', password='pass', host="localhost")

class Actor(Model):
    name = TextField(unique=True)

db.create_table(Actor)
```

Unfortunately, peewee doesn't seem to add `UNIQUE` constraints.

Output SQL:

```
-- Table: actor

-- DROP TABLE actor;

CREATE TABLE actor
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT actor_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE actor
  OWNER TO user;
```

And in fact I can add multiple rows with the same `name`.

Any idea of what's going wrong?
Thank you all very much in advance :)

I'm using postgres 9.3.10 if that matters... python 2.7.6, peewee 2.6.4 (tried different versions, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Model.create_table()` API, which handles creating table and indexes.

Alternatively, you can call `db.create_tables()`, which resolves model dependencies and creates multiple tables (and indexes) in the appropriate order.

`db.create_table()`, the API You're using, just creates the table itself -- no indexes.

So:

```
db.create_tables([Actor])
```

Or:

```
Actor.create_table()
```

Comment: My bad for assuming that create_table was the same as calling create_tables with one entry in the list... I have to say, though, that the naming is quite dumb. Anyway, thank you very much ;)

Comment: It's documented, even has a big warning: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database.create_table

Comment: Yeah I was really stupid haha. But my point is that it's still confusing and I would have personally given a different name given such very different behaviors. De gustibus ;) thanks again